# <p:commandButton> not working when disable="true" initially

Tags: jsf, button, primefaces

This is my ManagedBean:

```
@Named(value = "mrBean")
@RequestScoped
public class MrBean {

   public void laugh() {
      System.out.println("HAHAHA");
   }

   public void prepareToLaugh() {
      System.out.println("Drink water.");
   }

}
```

And this is the working version of my commandButton:

```
<p:commandButton actionListener="#{mrBean.laugh}" widgetVar="laughtButton"
                 value="Laugh" oncomplete="laughButton.disable();"  />
```

When I clicked the above button, I saw `HAHAHA` and the button is disabled. However, when I set the laughButton's `disable` attribute to `true`, the button does not work anymore:

```
<p:commandButton actionListener="#{mrBean.laugh}" widgetVar="laughtButton"
                 value="Laugh" disabled="true" oncomplete="laughButton.disable();"  />

<p:commandButton actionListener="#{mrBean.prepareToLaugh}"
                 value="Prepare to laugh" oncomplete="laughButton.enable();" />
```

When I click the 2nd button, I saw `Drink water` and the 1st button is enabled. However, when I click on the 1st button, nothing happens.

I'd be very grateful if someone could give me an advice on how I should tackle this problem. I'm using PrimeFaces 3.0 RC2.

Comment: @JigarJoshi: I'm not sure what you mean by "directly make it enable". In brief, if I don't initially set the `disabled` to true, it works. If I do, it doesn't work. =)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like as with `rendered` attribute, JSF re-evaluates the `disabled` attribute in the server side during processing of the form submit as part of safeguard against tampered requests and like. You're however enabling/disabling it by JS without notifying the server side of the changes.

You need to ensure that the value of the `disabled` attribute evaluates `false` during the request whenever you intend the button to be enabled during processing of the form submit. For example, bind it to a `boolean` property of a view scoped bean which is set by the other button.

```html
<h:commandButton disabled="#{bean.laughDisabled}" />
```

#### See also:

- [commandButton/commandLink/ajax action/listener method not invoked or input value not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked)

Comment: I have always been using this way. However, I saw PrimeFaces's client-side API earlier and I thought that I could save a boolean property. Turned out it's still needed :P. Thanks!

Comment: API is more like for visual helper for push buttons.