# page navigation not occuring after enabling button from row select using ajax

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using JSF 2.0 and primefaces 3.0 
I am trying to enable a command(Submit) button after a row select from datatable

```
     <p:datatable ....>
     <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" onstart="showImageButton.disable();" />
     <p:ajax event="rowSelect" onstart="showImageButton.enable();" />   
     </p:datatable>
        <p:commandButton id="commandbuttonid"    widgetVar="showImageButton"   action="#{bean.methodreturningapage}" value="Submit"
                ajax="false"  disabled="true" />
```

after selecting the rows command button gets enabled but the action method is not firing.

Answer (score 0):

Change the disabled attribute into something like `#{bean.buttonDisabled}`

take a look on this question

[p:commandButton not working when disable=“true” initially](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647315/pcommandbutton-not-working-when-disable-true-initially)

and this one

[Re-enabled p:commandButton not firing ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000669/re-enabled-pcommandbutton-not-firing-ajax)

Comment: bean is session scoped. Navigation is working if i remove the eanbling feature. but not after i add the above code.