# Prime faces commandbutton not working after enabled

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to enable a command button after a progress bar is completed, but when I load the page the commandbutton is already enabled, apart from this it works fine.

I have done some research and a similar issue:
[commandButton not working when disable=“true” initially](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647315/pcommandbutton-not-working-when-disable-true-initially)
But the solution did not worked for me.

What I am doing wrong? Is there something I am missing?

This is index.xhtml

```
            <p:growl id="growl" />
            <h3>Deskarga</h3>
            <p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true"
                closable="true" />
            <p:commandButton value="Start" type="button"
                onclick="pbAjax.start();startButton2.disable();"
                widgetVar="startButton2" />
            <p:commandButton value="Cancel"
                actionListener="#{progressBean.cancel}"
                oncomplete="pbAjax.cancel();startButton2.enable();" />

            <p:progressBar widgetVar="pbAjax" ajax="true" rendered="true"
                value="#{progressBean.progress}" labelTemplate="{value}%"
                styleClass="animated" interval="250">
                <p:ajax event="complete" listener="#{progressBean.onComplete}"
                    update="messages"
                    oncomplete="startButton2.enable();#{progressBean.setDisabled(false)};"/>
            </p:progressBar>


            <p:separator id="separator2" />

            <p:commandButton value="Parseatu" widgetVar="parserButton" ajax="true"
                disabled="#{progressBean.disabled}" actionListener="#{progressBean.parseatu()}"
                update="growl" />

        </h:form>
```

And this is the session scoped managed bean:

```
public class ProgressBean implements Serializable {  

    private boolean disabled= true;



    public boolean isDisabled() {
        return disabled;
    }

    public void setDisabled(boolean disabled) {
        this.disabled= disabled;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, You can't bean method in oncomplete attribute. This shouldn't work

```
oncomplete="startButton2.enable();#{progressBean.setDisabled(false)};"
```

If besides You want disabled ProgressBar component using oncomplete attribute, You should call javascript function. For this could to use [RemoteCommand](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/remoteCommand.jsf) or at least update disabled attribute on listener method

Secondly.

> when I load the page the commandbutton is already enabled, apart from
>   this it works fine.

CommandButton component have `disabled` attribute in `false` for default. If You want show disabled put attribute `disabled` in `true`

Comment: Thanks you for the answer,I will try using RemoteCommad, I am learning PrimeFaces and I only know the most common elements.

Comment: It solved my problem, thank you! But I also had to add a contructor to the bean setting disabled value to true.