# Enable p:commandLink when an input field is filled

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I needs to enable / disable commandlink depending text area.

Here is the code:

```
<p:inputTextarea id="inputTextarea" value="#{headerBean.dto.erganzendeInfo}" 
valueChangeListener="#{headerBean.eventValidator}" autoResize="false" 
onclick="enableField(inputTextarea)"> </p:inputTextarea>
<p:commandLink id="selectOneMenuId" widgetVar="selectOneMenuWidget1" 
oncomplete="PF('popUp').show();" styleClass="mediumButton" process="@this" disabled="#{headerBean.dto.headerSwitcherDto.lang}" update="message_popup">
<f:param name="newLink" value="YES" />

<h:graphicImage library="#{sessionData.theme}" name="images/message.png" /> </p:commandLink>
```

I try to set disable by the following: 
script

```
        function enableField(element) {
            PF('selectOneMenuWidget1').enable();
            document.getElementById("formId:selectOneMenuId").enabled = true;
            jQuery('#selectOneMenuId').val("enabled");

        }
```

but not successful.

Comment: Client-side enabling a disabled button does not work. Would be a security thing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647315/pcommandbutton-not-working-when-disable-true-initially

Comment: You should use the disabled attribute of your commandButton, which is managed from your back-end (ManagedBean), and use the onchange listener of the inputtext area to change the value of this attribute, and just use update from the onchange listener to update the button

Comment: @BugsForBreakfast its works for commandButton. But not works for my p:commandLink

Comment: Hmm are you allowed to use the rendered attribute instead?

Comment: no but disable condition there ' disabled="#{headerBean.dto.headerSwitcherDto.lang}"'